# BSOD при работе программы под .NET 4.6.2

Tags: c#, windows, bsod, .net-framework

Есть программа ("Электронной очереди") написанная на C# под фреймворк .NET 4.6.2
Программа должна постоянно крутится на сервере, но стали поступать жалобы, что компьютер перезагружается несколько раз в день, снял дамп, там присутствует постоянно 1 ошибка
SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION 0x0000003b. driver ntoskrnl.exe

[image: дамп ошибки]

Погуглив данную ошибку я нашел, что в причина скорее всего в железе (видео карты, память, HDD).
Моя программа также использует железо.
Я хотел спросить, может ли данный BSOD быть из за ошибок в коде, или это исключено и в любом случае будет только Exception уровня приложения.

1.
Программа использует сетевую карту. 
4 терминала по выдаче билетов, подключены по TCP/IP

2.
Программа использует 2 USB порта:
Конверторы RS-485 в USB, к ним подключены кассовые планшеты

3.
Карта передающая видеобуфер. 
Через эту карту подключены табло, через спец программу (Mars)
происходит захват видео буффера с областей экрана, эти области и идут на табло.
Карта вставлена в PCI слот и подключается как монитор по DVI.

4.
Вывод звука через встроенную звуковую карту.
Из низкоуровневых библиотек я использую Naudio.dll (Подтягивал через Nuget).

Объект важный, хотелось бы услышать ваши мнения.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Исключение [SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x3b--system-service-exception) означает проблему при переходе из кода уровня пользователя в код уровня ядра. Она может возникать например, из-за того, что данные, переданные модулю ядра, были каким-то образом повреждены и не было предусмотрено проверки их корректности. **Parameter 1** у BSOD - код исключения, 0xC0000005 соответствует [STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), т.е. произошла попытка обратиться к защищенной области памяти.

Причиной может быть как дефект железа, так и ошибка в коде драйвера (ошибка в коде .Net приложений напрямую обычно не вызывает такое исключение). Поскольку драйвера видеоадаптеров в Windows разделены на модули уровня ядра и уровня пользователя, наибольшее подозрение падает именно на них.

Для диагностики проблемы можно попробовать следующее:

1. Настроить windbg на правильные символы и попытаться получить стек вызовов и список загруженных модулей. Это поможет выявить, какие именно драйвера вызывают проблему.
2. Обновить драйвера до последних версий.
3. Те драйвера, которые уже были недавно обновлены, наоборот попробовать откатить на предыдущую версию (т.к. в новой версии могла появится ошибка). Если проблема не исчезнет, вернуть новую версию.
4. Заменять компоненты железа на заведомо исправные, и смотреть, на каком исчезнет ошибка.

Comment: Можно попробовать установить только непосредственно драйверы видеокарты, без управляющей пользовательской оболочки, но для этого нужно выкачать драйверы в виде зипа,  а не в виде инсталлера экзешника. Или отказаться совсем от брендовых драйверов, а откатится до универсального виндового драйвера, который устанавливается вместе с операционной системой.

Comment: Не, не всё так просто. Не может юзермодовский код завалить ядро без багов в драйверах или самом ядре. Так что это не ошибка юзера, а ошибка драйвера.

Comment: @VladD я не имел в виду, что пользовательский код является причиной. Переформулировал ответ.

Comment: @VadimTagil: Ага, стало гораздо лучше.

Comment: Спасибо всем за участие, в ночное время поставил все обновления на Win7, пока полет нормальный (сутки примерно). дальше посмотрю, самое главное я могу смело писать что проблема в драйверах.

Comment: @Aldmi любой bsod - это **всегда** проблема в драйверах или в железе